# uppercase constructor name error when using react-css-modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-css-modules

I have integrated [`react-css-modules`](https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules) into https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate, and am using it like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import CSSModules from 'react-css-modules';
import styles from './styles.css';

class Header extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <header styleName="app__header">
        // more content
      </header>
    );
  }
}

export default CSSModules(Header, styles); <--- error
```

However, JSLint is giving me an error:

```
error  A function with a name starting with an uppercase letter should only be used as a constructor  new-cap
```

How do I resolve this? I have written the JavaScript in the same way as the `react-css-modules` docs say to. The error seems to be `Header` shouldn't have a capital letter, but from convention I know classes should.

As an added bonus, if I could simply export `Header` without wrapping it in `CSSModules(Header, styles);` that would be great (e.g `export default Header extends Component {}`), however the docs don't mention this so am not sure if it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error due to your JSLint configuration which explicitly disallows this type of naming format.  Find more info here on that here: https://jslinterrors.com/a-constructor-name-should-start-with-an-uppercase-letter

It might be worth considering to change this rule, as in React you often use higher order components such as the one you are using which are usually named with an Uppercase format.

You could of course rename your imports as you like should you not wish to change the rule. example:

```
import cssModules from 'react-css-modules';

...

export default cssModules(Header, styles);
```

That would work, but you would have to decide on the convention for you team.